# Certain IP's return 'request timed out' but not others

Tags: windows

I have a hosting package on 1&1's servers but all the sites hosted on this (same IP's) return the 'request timed out' error. I know the IP is not down as it works on my phone through 3G. I don't have admin privileges for the router and I don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What router are you talking about?  One at work or at home or....? What device does not work?  Please provide more info

Comment: In addition to what dave asked how are you attempting to connect to the IP(s)? http, ssl, ssh, telnet, ICMP request ect?

Comment: I mean the one at home, my dad has all the access to it. Trying to connect over http to access my sites. Also when I ping the sites in command prompt it gives me the same error

Answer (score 1):

1&1 are notorious for blocking access at the inter router level. I had a server in the US once which could not deliver mails to any 1&1 service in Germany. When I asked my server's hosting company, they were so kind to trace the issue down: 1&1 had just blocked off any traffic from the subnet where my server was located, seemingly for protecting against a botnet. There was nothing I could do, and even after two years they did not unblock this IP range, so eventually I moved my server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you say 'on this' that the system you are testing your websites (also assuming) on are also the same machine the files are being hosted or your site.

Apache/PHP have a common issue where the local machine can sometimes not access the site on itself.

Comment: Sorry on this I mean on 1&1's servers. I can access ANY website at all except for mine hosted on the servers and they're all on a shared IP

Comment: As silly as it may sound, have you tried emptying your cache on your own system for that site and refreshing?

Comment: Yeah I have. It also gives the the same request timed out error when I ping using command prompt. Also when I go through an online proxy server (eg; hidemyass) it works fine

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of ideas, the only thing I've found that might help is Method 4 on this website. - http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-if-You-Can't-Access-a-Particular-Website